# implementing subgraph to subgraph isomorphism

Tags: isomorphism

Is there a way to get the biggest subgraph of graph A, which is isomorph to a subgraph of B?
I only have found several implementations for isomorphism of whole graph A to subgraph B. I could generate all subgraphs of A and get subisomorphism  to B. But the number of subgraphs of A is huge. There has to be a more efficient way to get the biggest subgraph to subgraph isomorphism.

Comment: Why assume that there is any efficient way? My hunch is that it is NP-complete (even though the complexity of the graph isomorphism problem itself is still unknown).

Comment: Sure, but for me the actual computation time needed for a problem of size 1000 is relevant. It makes a difference if calculating graph isomorphism for each of the thousands of subgraphs or doing a slightly more complex algorithm once.

Comment: Have you found anything in the meantime?